# Why does Coveralls coverage keep decreasing when I add more unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, travis-ci, googletest

**Issue**

I am writing unit tests for [this C++ project](https://github.com/arunumd/FractionClass.git) using Google Test framework. I have a weird problem wherein, when I create only one test suite, Coveralls gives a code coverage of about ~70 %. Whereas when I add two more additional test suites (extra ones to the previous) the code coverage drops very steeply to about ~25 %. I am very confused why does this happen? Is this normal?

**Extra Information**

- My project builds successfully (No bugs. Both the unit tests and the base project build and run successfully)
- Build is successful on Travis as well
- The unit tests are in the `/test` directory
- The header and source files are in the `/include` and `/app` directories respectively

Comment: i think the new tests you added  aren't exercising all code paths.

Comment: Code coverage on templates never worked for me quite well. It might help to add the test files to the code coverage sources, because the templates are instantiated in them.

Comment: @MikevanDyke tried this suggestion. Coverage still shows the same figure. But the suggestion is very interesting. Thanks for that